# How does a browser deal with applets?

Tags: java, browser, applet, japplet

I wonder what happens when my browser goes to a web-page like this. When I try to google for "browser" and "applet" mostly it finds how to add applet to browser and troubleshooting, but not how it works.

```
<html>
<head><title>My Applet</title></head>
<body>
    <applet code="org/mypackage/MainClass.class" archive="MyApplet.jar,libA.jar,libB.jar" width="1600" height="860"></applet>
</body>
</html>
```

If the web-page is remote then I guess browser has to download all mentioned jars in `archive` parameter to some temporary folder and then browser asks Java Plugin to process next. So the plugin would find then jar which has `MainClass` and would start Java program execution.

**Is my understanding correct?**

My applet requires many external jars, so I have packages only my classes into `MyApplet.jar`. Then in a separate folder I put

```
MyApplet.jar
libA.jar
libB.jar
applet.hmtl
```

And double click `applet.html`

In manifest for MyApplet.jar there is

```
Rsrc-Class-Path: ./ libA.jar libB.jar
Class-Path: .
```

**Is it really necessary to put these line in manifest?**

Comment: `code="org/mypackage/MainClass.class"` should be `code="org.mypackage.MainClass"` - the fully qualified class name, rather than the relative file path/name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is my understanding correct?

Basically, barring an applet deployed using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) and lazily downloading the library Jars either depending on need, or programmatically.

> Is it really necessary to put these line in manifest?

If the Jars are as follows they do not need to be referenced in the manifest.

- Listed in the `archive` attribute of the `applet` element.
- Listed in the `resources` section of the JNLP as a `jar` element.

Comment: JWS is a next step. But in this example would browser really download all those jars?

Comment: "If the Jars are as follows" as how? in the same folder?

Comment: *"in the same folder?"*  That is easiest.  Put them all in the same path represented by the code base.

Comment: I have added my answer as well, it is completely what I was asking. But I will not reaccept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is to answer my own question from Java Console:

```
CacheEntry[http://localhost/applet/MyApplet.jar]: updateAvailable=true,lastModified=Tue Jan 08 16:10:19 KST 2013,length=2128455
network: Connecting http://localhost/applet/MyApplet.jar with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://localhost:80/ with proxy=DIRECT
network: Downloading resource: http://localhost/applet/MyApplet.jar
    Content-Length: 2,128,450
    Content-Encoding: null

network: Wrote URL http://localhost/applet/MyApplet.jar to File C:\Users\Nikolay\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\cache\6.0\0\1367c940-4740e460-temp
security: The jar file isnt signed so the blacklist check will be skipped
security: Trusted libraries list file not found

cache: Replacing MemoryCache entry (cnt=0) for http://localhost/applet/MyApplet.jarwas=com.sun.deploy.cache.CacheEntry (749595) now=com.sun.deploy.cache.CacheEntry (15535897)
basic: Applet loaded.
basic: Applet resized and added to parent container
basic: PERF: AppletExecutionRunnable - applet.init() BEGIN ; jvmLaunch dt 1039162 us, pluginInit dt 903077 us, TotalTime: 1942239 us
```